# Probability question regarding Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

So my teacher was solving this probability exercise and she wrote :
$\Pr [|X- E(X)|< \varepsilon] >1- D(X)/\varepsilon^2$.
I know for sure that $\Pr [|X- E(X)| >\varepsilon] < D(X)/\varepsilon^2$ but how do we get from here, to the $\Pr [|X- E(X)|< \varepsilon] >1- D(X)/\varepsilon^2$?

Comment: if you set $\geq$ instead of $>$ (as it should be, I think), you get opposite event, so $\text{Pr}[A^C]=1-\text{Pr}[A]$

Comment: Oh I got it thanks.

Comment: I changed \text{Pr} to \Pr.